# Is there any way to filter out specific wavelengths

Tags: android, ios, camera, filtering, light

Please forgive me if this question had been asked  - I searched, but have been unable to find this, so again, please forgive if already asked.

What I'm wondering is if there is any way to filter out specific wavelengths of light programatically through a smartphone camera (ios or Android although ios is preferred).  This is a newer area for me, and while I've never built any camera apps, I have built other apps for ios.

I know that I can apply a physical filter in front of the lens to achieve results similar to what I want, but I'm wondering if I can use code to dispense with wavelengths outside my specific focus, or at least enhance the wavelength I am interested in that would drown out the others.  The wavelengths in question are from 600nm - 640nm which is a small set, but it's captured normally by the camera.  So, is it possible to focus on that set of wavelengths and filter out all others using code and not a physical attachment to the camera?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

And, again, if I have posted in the wrong area or incorrectly, please let me know and I will fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: If it is in a visible range you could just remove that color from all of the pixels in the image (I don't know what the visible range for light is off the top of my head), but that could be rather slow.

Comment: If it's possible, it would likely be in here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html. If not, it would have to be done in post-processing.

Comment: iOS has no support for this. You will have to post-process the colors of the captured image yourself.

Comment: OK - thank you for your help - I was hoping to process before the preview (in the viewfinder) as opposed to after the picture has been taken and written, then filtering out what I needed, but looks like it might not be possible - thanks!